# How to instantiate classes based on type in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-ioc

So I have a `BaseValuation` abstract class and it's implementations example `FooValuation` and `BarValuation`.

I want to instantiate `Foo` or `Bar` implementations depending on use input. So I created a simple class myself called `Valuation` which simply does this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Valuation;

class Valuation
{
    public $class;

    public function __construct($id, $type = 'basic')
    {
        $class = 'App\Valuation\Models\\' . ucfirst($type) . 'Valuation';

        $this->class = new $class($id);
    }

    public function make()
    {
        return $this->class;
    }
}
```

Using this I can simply do `(new App\Valuation\Valuation($id, $type))->make()` and I will get the desired implementation according to what the use asked for.

But I know that laravel's container is powerful and must allow me to do this somehow but I cannot understand how this will be done. Any ideas anyone?

Comment: Not sure if this answers your question, and I like your approach more, but PHP seems to be able to do this without any fancy coding: https://3v4l.org/3bS97

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can bind a class to any string, normally this is done in a service provider.

```
$this->app->bind('string', SomethingValuation::class);
```

Then you can instantiate this with `App::make('string')`.

I think this has more value when you're binding a single implementation (concrete) to an interface (abstract) rather than binding multiple classes.

You can also just allow Laravel to instantiate the class for you by calling `App::make(\Full\Path::class)`.

Both would allow you to inject a mock into the container with the same name for testing purposes.

Comment: But I still need to pass $id, should I use `makeWith` for that?

Comment: @Rohan The second argument of make() is an array of arguments to pass to the class.